# I am trying to split my variable by 2 vectors in R, but split() doesn't seem to work

Tags: r, dataframe, split

for example, if I had the following data set (see below), how would I split the data so that I could have the mean age for people with their own hair colour (like everyone who has red hair), by year? I have tried the split function, but it only allows me to make two-column subsets.

So my goal would be: the mean age of blonde people in 2016, mean age of brown haired people in 2016, etc. for every colour, for every year.

I am very new to R, so please answer in an easy to follow method (sorry lol).

```
Year    Age Hair Colour
2016    12  brown
2016    13  brown
2016    15  blonde
2016    18  blonde
2016    99  black
2016    1   black
2017    34  black
2017    28  green
2017    39  blonde
2017    58  red
2017    53  red
2017    5   brown
2017    65  blonde
2018    77  grey
2018    32  black
2018    22  brown
2018    33  brown
2018    44  brown
2018    63  brown
2018    63  green
2018    29  purple
2018    96  red
2018    15  brown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or in `data.table`

```
library( data.table )

DT <- fread("Year    Age Hair_Colour
            2016    12  brown
            2016    13  brown
            2016    15  blonde
            2016    18  blonde
            2016    99  black
            2016    1   black
            2017    34  black
            2017    28  green
            2017    39  blonde
            2017    58  red
            2017    53  red
            2017    5   brown
            2017    65  blonde
            2018    77  grey
            2018    32  black
            2018    22  brown
            2018    33  brown
            2018    44  brown
            2018    63  brown
            2018    63  green
            2018    29  purple
            2018    96  red
            2018    15  brown")

dcast( DT, Year ~ Hair_Colour, value.var = "Age", fun.aggregate = mean, fill = NA )

#     Year black blonde brown green grey purple  red
# 1: 2016    50   16.5  12.5    NA   NA     NA   NA
# 2: 2017    34   52.0   5.0    28   NA     NA 55.5
# 3: 2018    32     NA  35.4    63   77     29 96.0
```

Comment: I'm new to `data.table`. How would you create the output in a "long" format?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi again. Follow up question- I am trying to plot these values in a barplot; however, when I try, the year column shows up in my plot when I just want it to separate my x-axis values... is there a way to remove the column without removing its separating ability in this code?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Age ~ ., df1, mean)
#   Year HairColour  Age
#1  2016      black 50.0
#2  2017      black 34.0
#3  2018      black 32.0
#4  2016     blonde 16.5
#5  2017     blonde 52.0
#6  2016      brown 12.5
#7  2017      brown  5.0
#8  2018      brown 35.4
#9  2017      green 28.0
#10 2018      green 63.0
#11 2018       grey 77.0
#12 2018     purple 29.0
#13 2017        red 55.5
#14 2018        red 96.0
```

---

Or if we need wide format, use `tapply` from `base R`

```
with(df1, tapply(Age, list(Year, HairColour), FUN = mean))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Age = c(12L, 
13L, 15L, 18L, 99L, 1L, 34L, 28L, 39L, 58L, 53L, 5L, 65L, 77L, 
32L, 22L, 33L, 44L, 63L, 63L, 29L, 96L, 15L), HairColour = c("brown", 
"brown", "blonde", "blonde", "black", "black", "black", "green", 
"blonde", "red", "red", "brown", "blonde", "grey", "black", "brown", 
"brown", "brown", "brown", "green", "purple", "red", "brown")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
group_by(Year, Hair_Colour) %>%
  summarise(Age=mean(Age))
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   Year [3]
    Year Hair_Colour   Age
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>
 1  2016 black        50  
 2  2016 blonde       16.5
 3  2016 brown        12.5
 4  2017 black        34  
 5  2017 blonde       52  
 6  2017 brown         5  
 7  2017 green        28  
 8  2017 red          55.5
 9  2018 black        32  
10  2018 brown        35.4
11  2018 green        63  
12  2018 grey         77  
13  2018 purple       29  
14  2018 red          96
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!